# SoundCloud embedded track: How to refresh page after the track ends playing?

Tags: html, widget, embed, embedded-resource, soundcloud

First off, I am quite a noob.

Ok, so I have embedded a SoundCloud track into my webpage. My question is, how do you refresh a page (or do anything else) when the track ends?

Can you do it with getDuration(I found that on SoundCloud API page)?

I tried to code it. In the code I tried to get the duration of the track and then print it on the screen/webpage. What is wrong with this code?

```
<script src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<span id="headerLeft-content">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var duration = 0;
        (function(){
              var widgetIframe = document.getElementById('sc-widget'),
              widget = SC.Widget(widgetIframe);
              widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
                widget.getDuration(function(val) {
                  duration = val;
                });
              });
        }());

        document.write(duration);
    </script>
</span>
```

If that worked, I would just put something like wait(duration) and then refresh...

In other words, can soundcloud embedded track be "hacked" to loop(or to refresh page after track is over, that's what I want to do) even though the original widget doesn't support looping?

Please, take a look at the SoundCloud html5 widget page where I found getDuration command and see if you can help me... => http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#getters

EDIT:

```
<script>
var html=<iframe blablabla...></iframe>
document.write(html);
</script>

<script src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(){
    var widgetIframe = document.getElementById('sc-widget'),
        widget       = SC.Widget(widgetIframe),
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.FINISH, function() {
          window.location.reload(false);
    });
  }());
</script>
```

Page doesn't refresh after the track is over. Can you see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a function to the `SC.Widget.FINISH` event [documented here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#events). The following code snippet should work:

```
widget.bind(SC.Widget.FINISH, function() {
    window.location.reload(false);
});
```

Of course if all you want is for the widget to loop, you could use the `seekTo` and `play` methods:

```
widget.bind(SC.Widget.FINISH, function() {
    // again, again!
    widget.seekTo(0);
    widget.play();
});
```

That would be less intrusive than a page refresh.

Comment: Thanks for reply! My code looks like this now, but it doesn't seem to work (look at the EDIT part in the post)

Answer (score 0):

```
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Event.FINISH, function() {
    widget.seekTo(0);
    widget.play();
});
```

In the other reply, the first parameter is missing ".Event".

Answer (score 0):

**Finally.** A truly working version.

```
var widgetIframe = document.getElementById("soundcloud"),
    widget       = SC.Widget(widgetIframe);

widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, function() {
    widget.play();
});
```